# How to change google Line Chart with Customizable background color?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I need to show background colors on Y-Axis different ranges like if the line on map is in good (Green) or Average(Orange) or Poor(Red).

Please Help. 
[enter click to view Expected Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olCaY.png)